# Rooted Android Nexus 7 Lollipop disable SystemUI (system + navigation bar) ( C# for Xamarin )

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, root, statusbar

I use the following code to disable the navigation bar and the status bar on my 4.4 nexus device

```
    try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui" });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Main","Failed to kill task bar (1).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Main","Failed to kill task bar (2).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Works like a charm. But when i try to do the same on My Nexus 7. The screen goes black and I can't see my Application activity.

Am I doing something wrong here? is the command different for android 5.0?

Both devices are rooted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the above code does not work on Lollipop. The below code will work on older and newer versions of Android (tested on 5.0 and 4.4).

```
private void systemUIEnabled(System.Boolean enabled){

        try {

            Java.Lang.Process  process = Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.OutputStream);
            os.WriteBytes("pm " + (enabled ? "enable" : "disable") 
                + " com.android.systemui\n");
            os.WriteBytes("exit\n");

            Toast.MakeText (this, " UI Update , Post Reboot", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
            os.Flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
            Toast.MakeText (this, " UI Update , Error", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        }

    }
```

Updated :

The above solution is C# for Xamarin. Below is the Java code

```
public void setSystemUIEnabled(boolean enabled){
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
    os.writeBytes("pm " + (enabled ? "enable" : "disable") 
            + " com.android.systemui\n");
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but how can I use it on android studio? I paste it and give me some errors after doing imports